# Apache stuck on 'it works' page

Tags: apache, web

I can't get apache to load anything except the success or it works page. It is a fresh install so I made some changes to the default.

In httpd.conf

```
  <IfModule dir_module>
      DirectoryIndex index.html default.htm index.php index.pl
  </IfModule>
```

In httpd-vhosts.conf

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Users/thomasryan/Sites"
  </VirtualHost>
  <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Users/thomasryan/Sites/phpmyadmin"
        ServerName phpmyadmin.local
        ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin.local-error_log"
        CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin.local-access_log" common
        <Directory "/Users/thomasryan/Sites/phpmyadmin">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride None
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

In my hosts file I added

```
 127.0.0.1       phpmyadmin.local
```

This applies to any folder I use, not just phpmyadmin. I did a lot of googling and there seems to be nothing out there that I haven't tried so I'm looking for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you have a `NameVirtualHost` directive somewhere as well?

Comment: NameVirtualHost *:80 is in httpd-vhost.conf, is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Have you tried putting a `ServerName` into your first `VirtualHost` section as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would have appreciated some clarity on why this question was down-voted as it makes it difficult to improve on when there is no direction given.

Anyway the solution involved going to

```
  /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

and uncommenting this line

```
  #Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```